# Synchronized em métodos estáticos, e em métodos não estáticos

Tags: java, multithreading

Se eu tiver uma classe, onde eu tenha dois métodos um estático e outro não.

O lock é o mesmo ou não? Como fazer para os dois metodos compartilhare, o mesmo mecanismo de sincronizacao, ou seja, o mesmo lock?

```
class Foo{
    public synchronized static void test(){}

    public synchronized  void test2(){}

}
```

Esta seria uma classe Thread-Safe?

Answer (score 5):

Não é o **mesmo** lock, justamente por causa do `static`.

- **synchronized + static**: vai resultar numa instância única o que implica em um mesmo `lock` para todos que tentarem invocar.

  - Thread 1 chama: `Foo.test();`
  - Thread 2 chama: `Foo.test();`, ela vai ter que aguardar a primeira terminar.

- **synchronized - static**: vai resultar um `lock` pra CADA instância da sua classe `Foo`, sendo tratados de forma diferente.

  - Thread 1 chama: `foo1.test2();`
  - Thread 2 chama: `foo1.test2();`, ela vai ter que aguardar a primeira terminar.
  - Thread 3 chama: `foo2.test2();`, vai ser executado imediatamente, pois independente da outra instância.

O que vai garantir se é uma classe `Thread-Safe` ou não, vai depender muito do seu próprio código e com o que você vai manipular, ela será segura quando não ocorrer chances do dado ser corrompido pela alta concorrência. Então não necessariamente você precisa ter o `synchronized` dependendo dos dados que estiver trabalhando.

Comment: Legal @MaiconCarraro, interessante mecanismo. E como seria se eu quisesse que o lock do método statico fosse o mesmo do método não estático, em outras palavras, como fazer com ambos os tipos de método compartilhem o mesom mecanismo de sincronizacão?

Comment: Você diz do `test()` funcionar como `test2()`? Realmente não sei dizer, sei que ao contrário seria possível, mas talvez você queria brincar com [ReentrantLock](http://robaustin.wikidot.com/reentrantlock)

Comment: Se o método é estático, o lock é feito na classe `Foo.class`. Portanto basta fazer os métodos dinâmicos também terem o lock na classe `Foo.class` (isso é feito colocando o código do método dentro de um bloco `synchronized(Foo.class) { ... }` em vez de de declarar o método em si como `synchronized`).

Comment: @Piovezan, legal, ótima solucão, funciona mesmo!